# Error: colon expected css(css-colonexpected)

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a. Simple angular project.
In the css file /src/styles.css ,while writing the code, I'm facing being shown syntax errors.

```
body {
     margin: 0;
     background: #F2F2F2;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     height: 100vh;
}

#container {    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70px auto;
    height: 100%;

    #content {
        padding: 30px 50px;

        ul {//error highlight saying: colon expected css(css-colonexpected)

            list-style-type: none;
            margin:0;padding:0;

            li {
                background: #fff;
                border-radius: 8px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 8px;

                a {
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color:#00A8FF;
                }

                ul {
                    margin-top: 20px;

                    li {
                        padding:0;

                        a {
                            font-size: 1em;
                            font-weight: 300;
                        }//Error highlight saying: at-rule or selector expected css(css-ruleselectorexpected)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error msg shown as comments

Syntax errors being shown are:
-colon expected css(css-colonexpected)

-at-rule or selector expected css(css-ruleselectorexpected)

Comment: Seems to be valid SASS - https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/038090b045f9035d277ef3a65688a36b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a valid `SASS` or `SCSS` with nested classes in  a `.css` file and hence the error is shown. The equivalent `css` would be:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70px auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#container #content {
  padding: 30px 50px;
}
#container #content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container #content ul li {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#container #content ul li a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00A8FF;
}
#container #content ul li ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#container #content ul li ul li {
  padding: 0;
}
#container #content ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using **sass** in **CSS** file.. So this error is being shown. Its file extension should be .sass or stylesheet should be coded according to CSS syntax.

In CSS, it would be like:

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70px auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#container #content {
  padding: 30px 50px;
}
#container #content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container #content ul li {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#container #content ul li a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00A8FF;
}
#container #content ul li ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#container #content ul li ul li {
  padding: 0;
}
#container #content ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```